# how to sort data in each partition in spark?

Tags: apache-spark

There is some data:

```
a   2
b   2
c   2
a   1
c   3
a   3
c   1
b   3
b   1
```

when I repartition the data, and **no sort**, code is:

```
val sc = new SparkContext
val file = sc.textFile(args(0)).map { a => {
           val splits = a.split("\t")
           (new MyObject(splits(0), splits(1).toInt),"") } }
           .partitionBy(new MyPartitioner(3)) //.sortByKey()    no sort
```

The result is:

```
//file:part-00000
(a  2,)
(a  1,)
(a  3,)

//file:part-00001
(b  2,)
(b  3,)
(b  1,)

//file:part-00002
(c  2,)
(c  3,)
(c  1,)
```

when I repartition the data, and **sort**, code is:

```
val sc = new SparkContext
val file = sc.textFile(args(0)).map { a => {
           val splits = a.split("\t")
           (new MyObject(splits(0), splits(1).toInt),"") } }
           .partitionBy(new MyPartitioner(3)).sortByKey()
```

The result is(it is not I wanted, the sorted data affect original partitions):

```
//file:part-00000
(a  1,)
(a  2,)
(a  3,)
(b  1,)

//file:part-00001
(b  2,)
(b  3,)
(c  1,)

//file:part-00002
(c  2,)
(c  3,)
```

The result I expect is:

```
//file:part-00000
(a  1,)
(a  2,)
(a  3,)

//file:part-00001
(b  1,)
(b  2,)
(b  3,)

//file:part-00002
(c  1,)
(c  2,)
(c  3,)
```

Could you help me? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.OrderedRDDFunctions

Answer (score 8):

The `sortWithinPartitions` function of `Datasets` also works.

http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset

So, you can use the following style

```
df.repartition(col("A"), col("B")).sortWithinPartitions(desc("C")) ...
```